# Creating SQL Server database in (or attaching from) Google Drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, google-drive-api

I tried to create a new SQL Server database in my Google Driver folder but I cannot even navigate to my GD and when I paste in the path I keep getting acces denied even when SSMS is running as Admin.

Also tried creating the DB in usual SQL Server Data folder, moving to my Gooogle Drive and attaching from there by pasting in the path because I cannot navigate to GD when trying to attache an existing DB but again I get access denied error...

Anyway, did anyone manage to create in or attach from Google Driver folders an SQL Server database or has any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure syncing of the GD type can't handle something like SQL Server data files. Maybe you can put the backups there instead?

Comment: SSMS may be running as an admin, but the service account that SQL Server is using is the one that needs access to the folder. Can you verify that is the case?

Comment: I really doubt you can do this. Google drive isn't a real drive as such, it sync back changed datga to the cloud every so often via the a service associated with the Google Drive itself. This is going to conflict with SQL Server since it will want to have exclusive access to the physical DB (the .MDF file).

Comment: @Kevin, the SQL Server Service is loggion on as "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" but that is not a local user or group so how would I have to modify permissions of the folder in order for service to have access to that folder? I checked the permissions of the folder where SQL Server stores DB files by default and I see "MSSQLSERVER" user in there but when I try to add that user to the GD folder where I wanted to save the DB I get "An object named "MSSQLSERVER" cannot be found...

Comment: @AndrewBarber I have no intention of inserting any data into that DB, I just want to be able to work on the DB schema in multiple locations...

Comment: The user name is almost certainly going to be `networkservice`, but I'm going to guess you'll still have big trouble. This won't work as either a backup or replication strategy. What it sounds like you need here is a VPN.

Comment: @Kevin, I gave Full Control to my GD folder to NT Service\MSSQLSERVER and after that the SSMS was able to create a new DB there. Please post your comment as answer so I can give you credit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSMS may be running as an admin, but the service account that SQL Server is using is the one that needs access to the folder. Can you verify that is the case

Comment: The NT Service\MSSQLSERVER account needed permissions to the Google Drive folder where I was trying to create a new database. This account may be different on different computers as it can be specified under which credentials the SQL Server service will be running during SQL Server installation...